# pass Object as JSTL tag attribute

Tags: java, exception, object, attributes, jstl

I am trying to make a custom tag. In this tag, I will pass an Object as attribute and it should return an array list. I have tried it and I am getting an exception like.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.showtable.helper.ParentNode
```

I think my parameter is send as String to the class and there its not able to cast the object to the given type. How can I solve it and pass the Object itself and typecast it at the class(since String itself is an Class I think its possible, but i dont know how to do it)
 my code is given below.
inside page

**Inside page**

```
<%@taglib prefix="test" uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/ShowTableCustomTag.tld"%>
<%
//the 'theMainObject' is of type ParentNode
request.setAttribute("mainobject", theMainObject);
%>
<test:getorder objectpara="mainobject"></test:getorder>
```

**Inside ShowTableCustomTag.tld**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd">
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
  <short-name>showtablecustomtag</short-name>
  <uri>/WEB-INF/tlds/ShowTableCustomTag</uri>
 <tag>
    <name>getorder</name>
    <tagclass>cc.showtable.customtag.ParentNodeOrder</tagclass>
    <info>tag to return order as arraylist</info>
    <attribute>
      <name>objectpara</name>
      <required>true</required>
    </attribute>
</tag>
</taglib>
```

**Inside ParentNodeOrder class**

```
package cc.showtable.customtag;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport;
import com.showtable.helper.ParentNode;
public class ParentNodeOrder extends TagSupport{

     private Object objectpara;

    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {

        try {
            //Get the writer object for output.
            JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
            ParentNode parent=(ParentNode)objectpara;
            out.println(parent.getOrder());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }
    public Object getObjectpara() {
        return objectpara;
    }
    public void setObjectpara(Object objectpara) {
        this.objectpara = objectpara;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing this exception because you are missing the `<type>` tag inside your `<attribute>` tag in your `.tld` file.
The `<type>` tag is optional and an attribute without a `<type>` tag is assumed to be of `String` data type.
Also, you need to set `rtexprvalue = true`. The `rtexprvalue` stands for **Runtime Expression Value**. You need to set its value to true so that attribute's value can be dynamically calculated at runtime.
So your `attribute` declaration should be like this in your `.tld` file:

```
<attribute>
    <name>objectpara</name>
    <required>true</required>
    <type>com.showtable.helper.ParentNode</type>
    <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have inclduded the type, but sill I am getting the same exception :(

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.showtable.helper.ParentNode

Comment: Then i think you also need to set `rtexprvalue = true`!